# How to simulate Web page button click in code

Tags: c#, .net, button, onclick, simulate

I'm trying to simulate a button click in my program in order to get the response from the server. The problem is that the web page "onclick" activate a script in that page

The html look like this:

```
<script language=javascript>
    function frmsubmit(id)
    {
        document.all("HistoryData1_hiddenID").value=id;
        document.all("Form1").submit();  
    }
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Go" Class="RegularButton" onclick="frmsubmit('0')" >
```

I used this code that i have seen:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(url);
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
wb.Document.GetElementById("btnGo").InvokeMember("click");
```

Nothing happens. In the real web page I get an html with data that I need. Any ideas?

Comment: `HtmlElement btn = yourBrowserControl.Document.GetElementById("btnGo");
btn.InvokeMember("click");`

Answer (score 3):

you can use jquery like

```
$("#btnGo").click();
```

in your .cs you will use it like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {");
sb.AppendLine("$('#btnGo').click();");
sb.AppendLine(" });");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", sb.ToString(), true);
```

thats it, of course you have to add jquery libraries to html page

Answer (score 0):

Try calling doPostBack

```
__doPostBack("btnGo', '<event argument here>');
```

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function (or [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/), dependingo on your purpose).
I.e.

```
$('#<%=btnGo.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
```